# CSS or jQuery on rails / How to "fill frame" with an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, image, scaling

Whats the best technique for doing something like "fill frame" in indesign .. meaning take the image and scale the shortest side so it fits, then clipping the rest?

Is this possible with pure CSS ?

I am using Rails with jQuery..

The code could be something like this:

```
<div class="image_container"><img class="image" src=""></div>
```

Comment: Is this a background-image or an image?

Comment: it's an image.. something like this  <div class="image_container"><img class="image" src=""></div>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is impossible with pure CSS... might be able to give you a jquery solution if you're intrested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, if you had fixed size of image_container:

```
.image_container{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image_container img{width:200px;}
```

This will scale image by width and hide by height.

Answer (score 0):

That assumes that the image is longer on its height than its width. It will have a blank space for landscape images.